# User taken photo not converting to PDF using Swift 2

Tags: pdf, swift2, xcode7, photo

I have a project I'm working on using `Xcode7` and `Swift 2`.  I have a `ViewController` that allows the user to take a picture with their device camera.  It then loads the taken photo into a `UIImageView` and they can mail the photo off as a `PDF`.

To take the picture, I have a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `Action` code of:

```
@IBAction func takeScan(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    image.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I also have code for what happens with the image afterwards:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    // Dismiss imagePickerController

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    // Set the View Controller image to taken photo
    scannedPhoto.image = image

}
```

I have a `UIButton` for sending the photo as a `PDF` attachment.  It prompts the user to type a name for the `PDF` file and saves that name to a `variable`:

```
let nameText = nameSaveAlert.textFields![0]

// AUTO CAPITALIZE Input Alert Text
// Create a String
var textConvert = ""

// Set string to inputed text from user
textConvert = nameText.text!

// Creat NSString that takes the above string and capitalizes it
let capsWord: NSString = textConvert.capitalizedString

// Assign the capitalized name to variable for use
let pdfFileName = capsWord as String

// Convert image to data to be saved using JPG data and 90%
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.scannedRecipe.image!, 0.9)

// PDF Work
let pdfWidth = self.scannedPhoto.bounds.width

let pdfHeight = self.scannedPhoto.bounds.height

let pdfData = imageData as! NSMutableData
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pdfWidth, height: pdfHeight), nil)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
self.view.layer.renderInContext(context!)

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

It then opens the mail app and creates an email with the `PDF` as an attachment.  and I can send it off. Problem is, it seems to be taking a screenshot with the dimensions of the `UIImage` and saving that image as a `PDF` and not taking the actual image the user took.  Why? My goal is to take the user taken photo and convert to a `PDF` and mail off as an attachment.  Thank you.

**Update**:
I changed the `PDF` section of my code to look like this as was suggested:

```
        let pdfWidth = self.scannedPhoto.bounds.width

        let pdfHeight = self.scannedPhoto.bounds.height

        let pdfData = imageData as! NSMutableData
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pdfWidth, height: pdfHeight), nil)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Convert scannedPhoto to a type UIImage
        var imageConvert = self. scannedPhoto.image! as UIImage

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
        imageConvert.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        UIGraphicsPopContext()

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

The new problem is, I only a small left corner of the image now as a `PDF`.  How do I get the whole picture? I thought setting the `width` and `height` variables based on the `UIImage` would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should really be comment, but anyway. Isn't the `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData()` function meant to accept a NSMutableData object, which will become the output of the rendered PDF? Also, rendering the layer isn't a good idea, I would suggest rendering the image using something like this:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
yourUIImage.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
UIGraphicsPopContext()
```

In your code, you are requesting the view's layer to be drawn, which I presuming doesn't just contain the image. The code snippet above requests the image to be drawn in your PDF context, if you replace the `self.view.layer.renderInContext(context!)` part in your code with the code snippet above.

Have a look at the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData).

**EDIT**:

So I created a little test project to see if I could get things working for myself. I'll show you the code, then show the few points where you went wrong.

```
if let image: UIImage = self.scannedPhoto.image, // 1.
   let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9) {
    let pdfSize = image.size // 2.
    let pdfData = NSMutableData(capacity: imageData.length)! // 3.

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: pdfSize), nil)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    // required so the UIImage can render into our context
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    image.drawAtPoint(CGPoint())
    UIGraphicsPopContext()

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    // now pdfData contains the rendered image.
}
```

1. You didn't really go wrong here, I would personally use an optional binding. Check [this out](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData). The advantage of using this is that you can report the error to the user that something went wrong (rather than have you app crash).
2. This will fix your sizing issue. In your code, you used `self.scannedPhoto.bounds` which will return the size of the `UIImageView`. On a retina screen, this may actually be twice the size of the original image, which could be causing your sizing issues. Passing the actual size of the `UIImage` didn't cause any problems for me too.
3. You need to create some memory for the PDF operations to be recorded in. The docs for `UIBeginPDFContextToData()` state that this is an output parameter. I told `NSMutableData` to give it the capacity of the existing image data, however in reality, the size of the PDF context may vary. The problem with your code is that you overwrite the imageData with PDF data - which may or may not be expected.

Comment: I updated my code with what you suggested.  Now I'm only getting the small corner of the taken photo, as a PDF.

Comment: @ChallengerGuy Checkout my updated post. There were a few mishaps in your code, which I think were causing you problems.

Comment: What you said makes perfect sense.  I did a little tweaking but it worked perfectly.  The file size of the PDF was also better at 2.3MB versus the 7.8MB PDF on the small section of photo that I originally did.  I really appreciate your help. Thank you.